# How to display my particular section in uitableview always on top?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I had a tableview with sections and dynamic number of rows in each section. I want to make a particular section of my `UITableView` appear at the top by changing the content offset.  I am using the code below to try to achieve this:

```
[table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (([array count]-anIndex)*cell.height)) animated:NO];
[table reloadData];
```

(This is in `-viewWillAppear:`.)

But it is not working correctly. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Why not make that view as header of tableview

Comment: Did you try putting this in viewDidAppear ?